# Can you subtract one dataset from another in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

In Azure Data Factory, is it possible to subtract the matching contents contents of 1 dataset from another to create a new dataset?

For example...

Dataset A

| Email | Date |
| --- | --- |
| test@gmail.com | 2023-01-05 |
| test@gmail.com | 2023-01-07 |
| test@gmail.com | 2023-01-09 |

Dataset B

| Email | Date |
| --- | --- |
| test@gmail.com | 2023-01-05 |
| test@gmail.com | 2023-01-07 |
| test@gmail.com | 2023-01-09 |
| test@gmail.com | 2023-01-11 |
| test@gmail.com | 2023-01-15 |
| test@gmail.com | 2023-01-17 |

I want dataset C to be all the records in dataset B, minus the matching records in dataset A

The result would look like the following....

| Email | Date |
| --- | --- |
| test@gmail.com | 2023-01-11 |
| test@gmail.com | 2023-01-15 |
| test@gmail.com | 2023-01-17 |

How might I be able to achieve this in ADF?

Comment: Where are the datasets coming from? If both reside in a database, I'd perform this on the database level, as I don't think ADF can handle such operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use join transformations in dataflow within ADF to achieve this.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-join

You can use left join between the datasets and then via filter transformation remove the rows with null value for the other column thereby getting only the delta values in final set